Detect if an interlaced video frame is the Top or Bottom field?
I'm decoding video PES packets (packetized elementary stream) containing H.264/AVC and H.265/HEVC using libavcodec like this:
while (remainingESBytes > 0)
{
    int bytesUsed = av_parser_parse2(
            mpParser, mpDecContext,
            &mpEncPacket->data, &mpEncPacket->size,
            pIn, remainingESBytes,
            AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);

    // send encoded packet for decoding
    int ret = avcodec_send_packet(mpDecContext, mpEncPacket);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        // failed
        continue;
    }

    while (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(mpDecContext, mpDecFrame);
        /// Do stuff with frame ///
    }

    remainingESBytes = getMoreBytes()
}

Sometimes the input video is interlaced, in which case it seems avcodec_receive_frame is returning individual fields and not a merged frame of the top and bottom fields together.
I couldn't find any way for avcodec_receive_frame to emit a full, non-interlaced frame.
I can merge a top and bottom field together but I haven't found any way to identify if a given AVFrame is top or bottom.
How can I do that?
EDIT I
Looking at the log output from the decoder, it appears the decoder knows if the field is top or bottom (carried by SEI?) but still can't figure out how to access that information via the libavcodec API...
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] ENTER DECODE NAL TYPE 39. sei.ni_custom.type = -1
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] Set sei.ni_custom.type to -1.
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] ff_hevc_decode_nal_sei - s->ni_custom.type = -1
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] Decoding SEI [NAL Type 39]. ni_custom.type=-1
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] TOP Field
[hevc @ 0x1afcfc0] EXIT DECODE NAL TYPE 39. sei.ni_custom.type = -1


"which field first" should be stream metadata, maybe container metadata. -- if you want to deinterlace, reach for the filters... if the material is actually interlaced. -- just merging both fields gives an awful picture.

Hi Christoph, the content is actually interlaced (even though H.265 strongly discourages it). In this case, directly merging the fields is sufficient, no need for anything fancier like yadif, etc. Just need to know how to identify which field is which.

the docs on AVCodecContext::field_order seem contradictory to me. they say "encoding: set by libavcodec. decoding: Set by user." but I'm very unfamiliar with ffmpeg used as a library. unless someone here knows, you should probably ask on IRC, on libera.chat in #ffmpeg. or dig around in ffmpeg CLI's source and see what they do there. one hit talks of H264_SEI_PIC_STRUCT_TOP_BOTTOM_TOP and ..._BOTTOM_TOP_BOTTOM

Untested but in the meantime, you can try something like:
ret = avcodec_receive_frame(mpDecContext, mpDecFrame);
/// Do stuff with frame ///
        
if( mpDecFrame->top_field_first )
{
    //# first received picture for this frame is "top" field
}

Newer versions of FFmpeg have a different option:
ret = avcodec_receive_frame(mpDecContext, mpDecFrame);
/// Do stuff with frame ///

if( mpDecFrame->flags & AV_FRAME_FLAG_TOP_FIELD_FIRST )
{
    //# this picture is for "top" field
}
else
{
    //# otherwise this picture is for "bottom" field
}

